# Should you increase tap target size with text scale factor?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, font-sizes, scaling

When a user has difficulties reading text and has to increase the font size they use on mobile phone, should tap targets increase as well?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to evaluate the impact of the interface layout and design due to the scaling of font size to start with, not to mention whether the tap targets should increase in size as well.

Without some idea of what the interface looks like and focusing on just the mobile phone use case, you can almost be certainly that any change in sizing will have a significant impact on the user experience.

You'll need to weigh up the line width, line height and font size not as single independent variables/factors. This will allow you to retain the optimal content density and then you can also evaluate the other elements that require use interaction.